# Form data re-appears on pressing back button in browser

Tags: html, django, browser

I have a form on a webpage that submits post information to the server. All is working good except when i submit the form and press back button the data in the form re-appears instead of going to the previous web page. How can I prevent this? Also I want the previous web page to be reloaded again when i press back button.

Thank you.

Comment: are you displaying the result of your form submit with a redirection to a regular GET page ?

Comment: yes. im using django so in my view i have `return HttpResponseRedirect`. What should i be using?

Comment: seems right, maybe the browser is filling the form again while the web server returns an empty form.
In your question, do you want the empty form or the page even before that ?

Comment: i want the previous page on pressing back button. but whats happening is the form fields are getting populated with previous form data, instead of going to the previous page.

Comment: could you put online a quick sample of site exhibiting this problem ? I'm still unsure of how you get a result so different from your expectations.

Comment: I can't. Im still developing and there is no live version. But did you understand whats the problem? Thanks for the help anyway, ill be looking around on google..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40736/discussion-between-zeograd-and-h-h-h)

Comment: sorry but I haven't understood your problem after all.